# Haptic Feedback with Gingerbread on Samsung Galaxy mini 2

Tags: settings, haptic-feedback

How can I turn off vibrations when I long press on start screen (to add a widget, etc.) or in Opera mini when long press on a link?

Answer (score 3):

The Haptic Feedback is a global setting provided by your phone, you can turn it off by:

1. Click your device "menu" button";
2. Tap "Settings"
3. Tap "Sound";
4. Tap "Haptic feedback" to remove the green tick, thus disabling this feature.

### [What is "haptic feedback"?](http://www.mobileburn.com/definition.jsp?term=haptic%20feedback)

> Haptic feedback, often referred to as simply "haptics", is the use of the sense of touch in a user interface design to provide information to an end user. When referring to mobile phones and similar devices, this generally means the use of vibrations from the device's vibration alarm to denote that a touchscreen button has been pressed. In this particular example, the phone would vibrate slightly in response to the user's activation of an on-screen control, making up for the lack of a normal tactile response that the user would experience when pressing a physical button. The resistive force that some "force feedback" joysticks and video game steering wheels provide is another form of haptic feedback.

*More about this at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology).*

Comment: what is haptic feedback? my samsung mini 2 doesnt have it in settings and also iam having the same vibration problem

Comment: @lily I've updated the answer with a small description and example of Haptic Feedback. **Ps:** Does your device have Gingerbread installed?